# Publish JUnit test results in azure devops with a pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, junit, azure-pipelines

I am trying to publish some test results in JUnit format. I am doing this with a pipeline. The results have the following format

```
<testsuites>
<testsuite name="filename1.csv">
<testcase name="hashcode_comparison" time="0.001004934310913086">
<failure>
<![CDATA[ Test failed ]]>
</failure>
<tags>filename1</tags>
</testcase>
<testcase name="test_dataset_equality" time="0.004002809524536133">
<failure>
<![CDATA[ Test failed ]]>
</failure>
<tags>filename1</tags>
</testcase>
<testcase name="test_dataset_similarity" time="0.0">
<failure>
<![CDATA[ Test failed ]]>
</failure>
<tags>filename1</tags>
</testcase>
</testsuite>
<testsuite name="filename2.csv">
<testcase name="hashcode_comparison" time="0.002998828887939453">
<failure>
<![CDATA[ Test failed ]]>
</failure>
<tags>filename2</tags>
</testcase>
<testcase name="test_dataset_equality" time="0.025003910064697266">
<failure>
<![CDATA[ Test failed ]]>
</failure>
<tags>filename2</tags>
</testcase>
<testcase name="test_dataset_similarity" time="0.0019998550415039062">
<failure>
<![CDATA[ Test failed ]]>
</failure>
<tags>filename2</tags>
</testcase>
</testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

This is published properly in azure devops. It has been published in the test tab of the pipeline results (See image below).

[image]

Below is how I am publishing the test results

```
  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    inputs:
      testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
      testResultsFiles: '**/test_results.xml*'
      searchFolder: 'folderpath/'
      mergeTestResults: true
```

As you can see, it is working. However, I am missing the file name. I am trying to use the tag attribute, so it appears on that column in azure devops. This does not work.

Does anybody know how to publish the file name, in this case, the tag and also test suite name  in the azure devops test dashboard?

Thanks for your help!